# Jquery hide and show not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html

Whats wrong in this code ??

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#two").hide();

    $("li").click(function(){
      $("#one").hide();
      $("#two").show();
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#one").show();
      $("#two").hide();
    }); 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="one">
      <h2>change password</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h2>input text box</h2>
      <div>
        <button>Cancel</button> 
      </div> 
    </div>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

For the above mark-up ,when I click `$("li")` the code works fine.But when I click the button, the code doesn't work.

But if I replace the `$("li")` with `$("one"`) the code works completely. Not sure whats happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) as when button click handler is invoked the event is bubbles to `li` thus `li` click handler in also executed.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

*Code*

```
$("button").click(function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

    $("#one").show();
    $("#two").hide();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#two").hide();

   $("li").click(function() {
     $("#one").hide();
     $("#two").show();
   });
   $("button").click(function(event) {

     event.stopPropagation();

     $("#one").show();
     $("#two").hide();
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div id="one">
      <h2>change password</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h2>input text box</h2>
      <div>
        <button>Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```